# AccelStepper motor current position

Tags: library, stepper-motor

When using the AccelStepper library to control the motor, I need the current position of the motor at any given time when in motion. However, the functions in this library blocks so `currentPosition()` cannot return the position until the `move()/run()` function blocks completely to the desired/set position. How can I circumvent this to move and display the position simultaneously?

Comment: yes, you can ... step only one step at a time